# Obtaining MACs on a Layer 3 port via SNMP?

Tags: snmp, mac-address, cisco

I'm working on a script to map servers that are connected into our switches and routers.  I have it working to map layer two ports, using the algorithm listed at http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk362/technologies_tech_note09186a00801c9199.shtml to pull out the MAC addresses.

Layer 3 ports are another matter.  These are ports that don't show up in the 'sh vlan' command on a router/layer 3 switch.  Ideally, I'd like to use the MAC addresses present in these ports, underlying the layer 3 connection, as that's a bit more 'permanent' than the IP address - these do show up in the MAC-address table on the device.  However, the fact that these ports don't have an associated VLAN, and that the MAC retrieval via SNMP is VLAN-indexed, makes it quite difficult.

I've been banging my head against this for about a week or so, but nothing I try/find seems to allow me to get the non-VLAN MAC addresses.  Is it possible to map the layer three ports this way, or will I need to use layer 3 (IP address) mapping?

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected via layer 2 to the device, you could just use a ping on the layer 3 address to generate an arp lookup and then look in the arp cache for the mac... This would work for any layer 3 port, even logical ports like the layer 3 version of Portchannels.
This is probably the easiest way.

If you want to be 100% in the realm of SNMP:

To get the interface table for that device, walk the below oid.  It will return
the list of all interfaces on that device.  This should work on any device (even a server) runnning a SNMP agent:

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2
```

This will give you a list of interface numbers (last digit in OID), and the interface descriptions.  It works for SVI and physical interfaces, not sure about logical types other than SVI.

Then for each interface, to get it's mac (where x is the value in the interface table):

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.x
```

This gives you the mac. (Leading 0's can be truncated on some devices.)
However, you will need atleast 1 layer 3 address on each device to do the snmpwalk and get.

If you just want all the macs, then walk this oid:

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6
```

I use this approach to do something similar on a large network.

Comment: FYI, this doesn't give you the connected mac address. This gives you the mac address of the interface.